# With Google Enhanced ecommerce, what should the quantity value represent when adding/removing from cart?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

When firing the `add_to_cart` or `remove_from_cart` events in Google analytics, what should the `quantity` value represent? Should it be the value you are adding/removing or the updated quantity of that product in the customer's cart?

For example, with the following code, does Google now think there are 4 of the item in the cart or 2?

```js
gtag('event', 'add_to_cart', {
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "P12345",
      "name": "Android Warhol T-Shirt",
      "quantity": 2,
      "price": '2.0'
    }
  ]
});
gtag('event', 'add_to_cart', {
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "P12345",
      "name": "Android Warhol T-Shirt",
      "quantity": 2,
      "price": '2.0'
    }
  ]
});
```

Different analytics tools seem to handle this differently and the GA docs don't make it clear to me what the value should be.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on my personal experience (trial and error) I was able to figure it is the number of items you are adding/removing from the cart. Not the number of items you have in your cart after adding/removing items.

And I agree, the documentation should be more explicit about this.

Comment: I appreciate your answer here, but is there any official documentation you can link to or possible test we can perform to get this result? Thanks!